# Global message disappeared after server switch

Tags: php, magento

i just transfered a fully developed magento site from development server to staging server, but i'm facing several issues.

I'm missing global messages in the back office, a.k.a success/error messages when you edit/create/save product or content. These messages appears in frontend though, when i subscribe to newsletter for example i get a thank you message.

Since this is the same code and database on both servers, i think this is a server configuration issue, but i can't see which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

1) First, go to your Admin Panel and Login

2) Choose "System"/"Configuration"

3) In the left-hand sidebar, scroll to the bottom of the page and find the section titled "Advanced," and click on the sub-tab titled "Advanced."

4) One of the first options on this new page should read "Mage_AdminNotification". Find this item in the list and then check if this part is: "Disable" if yes, put it to "Enable".

Also try to empty all cache - flush all.

Comment: Doing your test all my configs were OK, i submitted the advenced panel to be sure values were applied, a confirmation message showed up. The server switch blocked also content editing from the BO, this bug seems to block error/success messages on failed edits as well.

Comment: Are you sure that all files were copied correctly? sometimes there is a issue when some model or controler file is missing/corrupted. Also did you set permissions for files correctly? Also can cause several problems.

Comment: no, just talked to my sysadmin, he edited the magento .htaccess to manually strip the index.php from admin. We installed the extension http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/clockworkgeek/extension/3692/clockworkgeek_adminrewrites instead, now everything works fine, thanks :)